# What does the "system" version mean in node version manager?

Tags: node.js, nvm

```
->     v14.17.0
         system // What is this???
default -> 14.17 (-> v14.17.0)
node -> stable (-> v14.17.0) (default)
stable -> 14.17 (-> v14.17.0) (default)
```

Just as the title states, what does "system" exactly mean in nvm version list? Is it safe to delete it? Does it have any impact on my node applications being ran?